# Autocomplete onclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually, I have done jquery autocomplete on focus,when I click my textbox it shows focus of all data,so I want if i'm clicking any one data means it redirects to page how will do that.
Something like this: [www.practo.com](https://www.practo.com)

This is my script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
source: 'search.php',
minLength: 0,
scroll: true
 }).focus(function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML also. can you do on keyup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery UI autocomplete select(event, ui)](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) to enable redirection after user selects an item. See demo below:

```js
var sample_skills = [
      "jquery",
      "java"
    ];

$(function() {
 $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
  source: sample_skills,
  minLength: 0,
  scroll: true,
  select: function(event, ui) {   
   console.log(ui.item.value);
   if(ui.item.value == "jquery"){
       location.href="https://api.jquery.com/";
   } else if (ui.item.value == "java"){
       location.href="https://www.w3schools.in/java-tutorial/intro/";
   }
  }
 }).focus(function() {
  $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <input type="text" id="skills">
```